# nginx cannot find js files under the assets folder

Tags: http, web, nginx, server, configuration

I have a compiled Angular application located on my local disk.
Trying to run it on nginx server.
Added the following configuration:

```
server{
   listen 8080;

.......

       location /myapp/ {
            root C:/myapp/;
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ =404;
       }
```

index.html file in project root contains references to js files, located in myapp/assets/js folder:

```
<script src="/assets/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

But when I run it on server, I get index.html file, it opens, it tries to locate file in http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/js/polyfill.min.js, avoiding root "myapp", which leads to 404 error.

Adding additional location "location /assets/" doesn't solve the problem.
Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: when I try to replace "root" with "alias", it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I have the same issue

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Currently not working on this project anymore, sorry.